# Get position of a specific item in an Array based on a string value

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, position

I have a basic data model that includes a string value. This model is returned in an Array.

**My data:**

```
fun getFruits() : Array<FruitModel>{
    return arrayOf(
        FruitModel(name: "Apple"),
        FruitModel(name: "Tomato"),
        FruitModel(name: "Pear"),
        FruitModel(name: "Plum"),
        FruitModel(name: "Banana"),
        FruitModel(name: "Watermelon"),
        FruitModel(name: "Strawberry"),
        FruitModel(name: "Blueberry"),
        FruitModel(name: "Blackberry")
    )
}
```

**I need to get the position of a specific item based on the fruit name.**

**Example:**
If I specify "Plum", I will get 3.
If I specify "Blueberry", I will get 7.

How do I get the position of items in an array based on a string value (in this case, `name`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `indexOfFirst` method of `ArrayList` for this

```
val fruits = getFruits()
val index = fruits.indexOfFirst { it.name == "Plum" }
```